# How to share a Google Spreadsheet that utilizes Google App Scripts within a company domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a seemingly simple problem that seems to get more complicated the more I get into it.

I have one spreadsheet document.

This spreadsheet utilizes a google apps script, that in turn utilizes various APIs:  Domains, Sites, Spreadsheets...

To use this spreadsheet I have to take a few steps -

1. Authorize the spreadsheets.  This dialog only comes up if I use the
   script editor, otherwise the Spreadsheet fails silently.
2. Enable Domain API in Editor -> Resources -> Advanced Google Services
3. Enable Domain API in Google Developer Console to a seemingly hidden
   project that is attached to my spreadsheet.  The only way I can access this secret page is through the Advanced Google Services menu in step #2.

After getting through these hurdles, the spreadsheet now functions correctly without having to use the Script Editor.

Now I want to share this spreadsheet with other users in my company's domain.

Is there any easy way to do this, or will every single user I share it to have to jump through these hurdles as well?

Am I thinking about this wrong?  The documentation states the script is 'attached' to the spreadsheet.  But the more I get into it, the more separate these two things seem to be.  I can share a spreadsheet - but the script won't function properly.  I can publish a 'web app' with the script editor - but it won't come with the spreadsheet.

Any help appreciated
Frusteratingly yours...

Answer (score 2):

Other users will have to have the same domain permissions as you do.

An approach you could take is have all the permissions related work done on a script that is published as a web app that will take url parameters (to trigger tasks), which is run as you and accessible to others.

From there, your original script can call the published url and send instructions via parameters.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content